# Old domain was removed and Unable to login as domain administrator account in windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, login, domain

I have a problem with a laptop that is in an old domain.  I need to uninstall some of the  programs on that  machine.  For that, it is asking for the administrator password. The old domain’s administrator account password is not accepted and there is no other local administrator account configured on that machine.  How can I log into that machine and join it to the new domain?

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 0):

If you can gain access to the hard disk (e.g. by connecting it to another system or by booting from a repair  disk) it is rather easy to hack into your system.

This article explains how.
http://carnal0wnage.attackresearch.com/2012/04/privilege-escalation-via-sticky-keys.html

Once you have a command prompt you can reset the administrator password by using this command:

```
net user administrator <password>
```

Comment: That is windows 7 laptop, by default the local administrator account is disabled, cant enable that without domain administrator rights. So, I am trying to create a new admin user account on that machine with the help of Hiren's Boot CD, hope it works.

Comment: You can enable the local administrator user with the command 'net user administrator /active:yes'. The command prompt that you have after following the instructions will have system rights.

Comment: to do that i need local admin rights at least...

Comment: Just try it. It will work.